# Minimum Servlet API version for JAX-RS 1.1

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

What minimum version of the Servlet API is required to run JAX-RS 1.1 (for example Jersey 1.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [mailing list](https://jersey.dev.java.net/servlets/ReadMsg?list=users&msgNo=9607) the minimum version of the servlet API is 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

The [JSR](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr311/index.html) refers to Java Servlet Specification Version 2.5.

**Edit**: The version is mentioned in the bibliography on the last page of the JSR PDF.